# DISM fails with 'There is not enough space on the disk.' while capturing an image

Tags: images, clone, disk-image, wim, dism

I use DISM to capture images and store them on a network disk. I use a standard 32bit WinPE 4.0 environment to capture them.

My current path was set to `i:\images` and I executed the following command:

```
dism  /capture-image /imagefile:ae2212-w81-64bit-v1.wim /capture-dir:c:\ /name:system
```

It ran up to 100% and which point it failed with the error `There is not enough space on the disk.`. During capture I monitored the network drive and I could see the image growing. When the error message occurred the image was deleted.

What is odd is that the image would have been about 15GB and the network drive has over 500GB free.

What could be going wrong, should I use the `/scratchdir` option?

```
2014-02-19 01:04:37, Info                  DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=1216 c:\Windows.old\Windows\WinSxS\x86_wcf-m_svc_mon_sup_dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16432_none_a2bd221c1cde6e62\ServiceMonikerSupport.dll (HRESULT=0x8007011A) - CWimManager::WimProviderMsgLogCallback
[1216] [0xc144012f] 
2014-02-19 01:04:37, Info                  DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=1216 c:\Windows.old\Windows\WinSxS\x86_wcf-system.identitymodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.2.9200.16432_none_30a420f7f05ab330\System.IdentityModel.dll (HRESULT=0x8007011A) - CWimManager::WimProviderMsgLogCallback
[1216] [0xc144012f] 
2014-02-19 01:04:37, Info                  DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=1216 c:\Windows.old\Windows\WinSxS\x86_wcf-system.runtime.serialization_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.2.9200.16432_none_123c6840d0913997\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll (HRESULT=0x8007011A) - CWimManager::WimProviderMsgLogCallback
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
[1216] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(141): There is not enough space on the disk.
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Error                 DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=1216 TID=1220 base\ntsetup\opktools\dism\providers\wimprovider\dll\wimmanager.cpp:1217 - CWimManager::Capture(hr:0x80070070)
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Error                 DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=1216 TID=1220 base\ntsetup\opktools\dism\providers\wimprovider\dll\wimmanager.cpp:4274 - CWimManager::InternalCmdCaptureBase(hr:0x80070070)
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Error                 DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=1216 TID=1220 Error executing command - CWimManager::InternalExecuteCmd(hr:0x80070070)
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Error                 DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=1216 TID=1220 base\ntsetup\opktools\dism\providers\wimprovider\dll\wimmanager.cpp:1928 - CWimManager::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070070)
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: WimManager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80070070
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1216 TID=1220 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1216 TID=1220 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1216 TID=1220 Disconnecting Provider: WimManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1216 TID=1220 Disconnecting Provider: VHDManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1216 TID=1220 Disconnecting Provider: GenericImagingManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1216 TID=1220 Disconnecting Provider: Compatibility Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2014-02-19 01:56:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1216 TID=1220 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the boot device (USB or CD/ROM) the capture process makes a decision of where to write its scratch files.  Since a USB is writable, it tries to write massive scratch files to it.  Try using the /scratchdir option and direct scratch files to media with plenty of room.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing the "scratch directory" I increased the scratch space on WinPE (the default is 32MB).  This worked for me:

> DISM /Mount-Wim /WimFile:<*imagepath*> /index:*indexnum*
>   /MountDir:<*mountdirlocation*>
>
> **DISM /image:<*mountdirlocation*> /set-ScratchSpace:512**
>
> DISM /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:<*mountdirlocation*> /Commit

Set the scratch space as high as the systems you are trying to image will support.  Valid values for the scratch-space are 32, 64, 128, 256 and 512 (MB).

More info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799261(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem where the image fails around 60%.  Like you, I have nearly a terrabyte free and there are no quota management features enabled on the servers.  I'm using Windows PE4 32bit booted off a flash drive and the latest version of DISM.

The added complication is that I'm capturing to a DFS enabled share. Usually re-capturing the image succeeds so I'm not sure if my secondary fix of using a non-namespace share name the second capture works because I got lucky or if there is an issue with the namespace.  I wish I had a better answer for you but you might have to capture it to flash drive and manually copy later.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on a VM that only had 1gb of memory assigned to it.

After assigning 4gb of memory it worked fine.

Comment: That actually helped me; due to Hyper-V dynamic memory my virtual machine failed to get enough RAM to be able to install through either the normal means or the manual dism apply-image one. Thanks. (the scratch directory option did *not* work)